# Get azure Managed Identity ID with Terraform

Tags: terraform-provider-azure

I've looked around the Terraform data source for Azure rm and can't find what I'm looking for. How can I get an azure Managed Identity ID with a Terraform data source?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two types of managed identities: **System-assigned** and **User-assigned**.

Some Azure services allow you to enable a managed identity directly on a service instance. For example, you can enable a managed identity on an Azure VM with an [identity](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/virtual_machine#identity) block. Also, you can export the `identity` attributes and access the Principal ID via `${azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity.0.principal_id}`.

If you are using this [data source](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/data-sources/virtual_machine) to access information about an existing Virtual Machine. You can export the following via the `identity` block.

```
output "identity" {
   value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity
}
   
output "identity_identity_ids" {
   value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity.*.identity_ids
}

output "identity_principal_id" {
  value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity.*.principal_id
}

output "identity_tenant_id"{
   value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity.*.tenant_id
}

output "identity_type" {
    value = data.azurerm_virtual_machine.example.identity.*.type
}
```

Result

[image]